# Linux cut command - capture string between multiple positions

Tags: linux, sed, cut

I have a text file containing very long lines.  I want to get only parts of the file by specifying several positions.

I tried `cut` but it seems to give just the opposite reverse of what I need; it captures only what I don't want.

My cut code:

```
/bin/cat file.txt | /usr/bin/cut -f50-62,3414-5706427
```

My expected result is to have the entire file except for characters 50-62 and characters 3414-5706427.

I've also thought of `sed` but found no way to make `sed` get me out just the data I need. Is there any Linux command to reverse the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**edit:** there is an option to `cut` which looks like it does what you want:

```
echo "abcdefghikjl" | cut -c2-4
bcd
echo "abcdefghikjl" | cut -c2-4 --complement
aefghikjl
```

Otherwise, you could use native bash [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

function revcut() { 
    echo "${1/${1:$2:$3-$2}/}"; 
}
```

usage:

```
revcut "some string" start end
```

from a file:

```
revcut "$(cat filename)" start end
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you want a specific of characters, use `-c`</strike>

`-f` is for fields where you specify the field separator with `-d`

`sed` will do the job for you: (my arithmetic may be a bit off)

```
sed -r 's/(.{49}).{13}(.{3360}).{5703013}/\1\2/'
```

Comment: thanks glenn, the -c does make sense but the main part of my question was how to get the values who are not in the specified ranges.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't entirely clear whether your positions are byte positions in the file as a whole, or column positions in files with very long lines (lines of 3 KB are unusual, let alone 5 MB).

However, you can deal with selecting the information on long lines using `cut`:

```
cut -c 1-49,63-3413,5706428-    # character positions in each line
cut -c 1-49,63-3413,5706428-    # byte positions in each line
```

The difference between bytes and characters matters if you are using UTF-8 as the code set (and any of the characters in the file is not in the ASCII subset of UTF-8).

If you are dealing with positions in a file, then your options are more limited.  Most Unix utilities are based around lines rather than anything else.  One clumsy option would be the `dd` command:

```
{
dd if=file bs=1 offset=0       count=49             # 1-49
dd if=file bs=1 offset=63      count=$((3414-63))   # 63-3413
dd if=file bs=1 offset=5706428                      # 5706428-EOF
} > output
```

You might need to adjust the numbers to compensate for 0-based vs 1-based arithmetic.